# Fix the "Sisters" tag please

Tags: support, tags

[Someone created a tag](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50772/were-tina-fey-and-john-cena-digitally-enhanced-in-sisters-2015) for the Tina Fey film "*Sisters*" but made the tag [sister](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sister).

I tried to fix it but the stupid system won't let me because it's too similar or something idiotic.

It says something along the lines of:

> You are attempting to create the new tag [sisters](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sisters); but the tag [sister](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sister) already exists! If you think this new tag should be created, raise it on meta.

Can a mod please fix this?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251478/clean-up-of-run-together-hyphenated-and-singular-plural-tags Plural tags are blocked by the system. You will basically need to wait for sister to be deleted by the system as a 0 question tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added the correct tag [sisters](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sisters) to the question. The old tag [sister](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sister) will get auto-deleted after a day since it has no questions anymore now.